# Is there a way to insert a function to round to 2 decimal places?

Tags: python, math, decimal

I'm trying to figure out how to get the result of mpg for these cars and have them rounded down to 2 decimal points.

```
cars = [
{"make": "Ford", "model": "Fiesta", "mileage": 23000, "fuel_consumed": 460},
{"make": "Ford", "model": "Focus", "mileage": 17000, "fuel_consumed": 350},
{"make": "Mazda", "model": "MX-5", "mileage": 49000, "fuel_consumed": 900},
{"make": "Mini", "model": "Cooper", "mileage": 31000, "fuel_consumed": 235},
]


def calculate_mpg(car):
  mpg = car ["mileage"] / car["fuel_consumed"]
  return mpg
  
def car_name(car):
  name = f"{car['make']} {car['model']}"
  return name
  

def print_car_info(car):
  name = car_name(car)
  mpg = calculate_mpg(car)
  
  print(f"{name} does {mpg} miles per gallon.")

  
for car in cars:
  print_car_info(car)
```

Comment: round(1.2345, 2)  if you want to always round down (rather than nearest) use math.floor(1.2345 * 100)/100

Comment: Don't you wanna round down? then **round(mpg-0.05, 2)** is right.

Comment: Use `f'{mpg:.2f}'` when you print it

Comment: Interestingly the way you'd do this in C (subtracting fraction before round) is considerably slower than using the math library. See gist: https://gist.github.com/the-moog/eee29531f3f6fd5853cf6e5188ed4cf0

Comment: @GraphiteBlimp:  Please clarify the question phrasing is correct and that you always want to round down?

Answer (score 0):

Use NumPy

```
np.round(mpg, 2) ## Rounds to two decimal places
```

Comment: Why would you introduce an unnecessary dependency on NumPy when Python has a perfectly good built-in `round` function? In any case, the OP almost certainly needs string formatting rather than numeric rounding.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something like

`round(x, y)`

with `x` being the number you want to round and `y` being the number of decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

I got something from both answers and I figured it out in line 11:

```
def calculate_mpg(car):
  mpg = car ["mileage"] / car["fuel_consumed"]
  return round(mpg, 2)  # I need to change the return in the calculation.
```